# How to reproduce this digital document scan effect using python?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, ocr, digital-handwritting

I want to reproduce the quality to scan of an APP, that app get images like this one: [RGB image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfgKl.jpg) and produce good results, like this: [image procesed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQZ9O.jpg). I have already used adaptiveThreshold, [adaptative_thresholding](https://github.com/pedrofrodenas/image-thresholding-OCR), otsu filter, etc, but they all just throw me in binary. I do not get the effect of removing noise from paper and obtaining the lines of the image in gray scale. Any idea about to solve this problem?

Comment: any comment about it?

Comment: Here’s something that could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42257173/contrast-stretching-in-python-opencv