# Read and display RAW10/V4L2_PIX_FMT_SRGGB10 ('RG10') media format in Python

Tags: image-processing, video-processing

The V4L2_PIX_FMT_SRGGB10 ('RG10') media format properties are as follows:

Each color component is stored in a 16-bit word, with 6 unused high bits filled with zeros.
so the depth is

depth: 10 ( 10 bits expanded to 16 bits with 0s in 6 MSB bits)
something like 000000xx xxxxxxxx

Each pixel consists of 2 colors R and G , so the stride is the distance between pixels, If we want to go from one pixel to the next , then the
length is,
Rlow + Rhigh + Glow + Ghigh = 8 + 8 + 8 + 8 = (in bits) 32 or 4 bytes

offset for R is 0 bytes and G is 2 bytes

I have an image with the following properties (I assume) , I guess this image is similar to RAW10, I just need to know how to read and display this image with correct parameters in python?

I have attached the image below:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tmxDUUG4iiuXGHhezZkszmCMx1_uUlY_/view?usp=drive_link

The dimensions of the image are as follows,
width=4056, height=3040

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry added more details for the above

Comment: Share your image - use Google Drive or Dropbox and be sure to give its width and height.

Comment: Hi , I have attached the image in the question

Comment: Please give width and height too. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention it, I have included the dimensions, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an attempt at reading this and wanted to share what I got so far - maybe you, or some other intrepid StackOverflower, can improve it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

# Define width and height, open file and reshape
w, h = 4056, 3040
d = np.fromfile('SRGGB10test_fin.raw.raw', dtype=np.uint16).reshape((h,w))

# Red is every second row, every second column, starting from 0
R = d[0::2,0::2]
# Green is every second row, every second column, starting from 1
G = d[1::2,1::2]
# Synthesize Blue channel as being equal to Green
B = G

# Stack channels to make BGR image amd save
BGR = np.dstack((B,G,R))
cv.imwrite('result.png', BGR)
```

That gives this:

[image]

And if you rotate and enhance contrast, you get this:

[image]

Comment: May I also know how did you enhance contrast?

Comment: You can use Fred's example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59515897/2836621

Comment: Thanks @Mark Setchell , left shifting Red and Green by 6 bits gives more details in terms of color.

Comment: Yeah, you can change the last line to `cv.imwrite('result.png', BGR<<6)`